# Function initiated in ajax call only works one time

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using a plugin called [mixitup](https://www.kunkalabs.com/mixitup/) that makes sure I have a masonry layout with some animations.

The masonry comes from another page which gets loaded in through ajax. I have a search bar which searches for photos and returns them from the masonry page. The issue is this works the first time but not the second time and so on. Why is that?

My code for the search input:

```
$('.photosearchinput').keyup(function(e) {
  clearTimeout($.data(this, 'timer'));
  if (e.keyCode == 13){
    searchphotos(true);
  }else{
    $(this).data('timer', setTimeout(searchphotos, 500));
  }
});
```

My function that makes the ajax call and which has my masonry mixitup function in the `complete`:

```
function searchphotos(force) {
  var photoform = $(".photosearchform").serialize();
  $.ajax({
   type:'post',
   url:"includes/photoresults.php",
   data:({photoform: photoform}),
   success:function(data){
     $( "#searchphotos" ).show().empty().append( data );
   },
   complete:function(){
     // I tried calling #masongallery from the body (body always stays the same and does not get added again)
     $('body').find('#masonrygallery').mixItUp({
       selectors: {
         target: '.tile',
         filter: '.filter',
         sort: '.sort-btn'
       },
       animation: {
       animateResizeContainer: false,
       effects: 'fade scale'
       }
     });
   }
 });
}
```

I thought maybe the DOM gets reloaded and jquery cannot find the element `#masonrygallery` anymore so I tried calling it like this: `$('body').find('#masonrygallery').mixItUp({` the `body` never gets reloaded so maybe this would fix it, but no. I get the same result. It works the first time, but not any time after that.

I have made a video to show what I mean: https://streamable.com/njy6x7

I get no errors in my console. And when I look in the network tab to see what ajax is retrieving, I see the correct images, they are just not visible as masonry layout (in fact they are not visible on the page at all but this is because of the plugin).

Comment: So the AJAX is invoked and receives the expected response on the subsequent (non-working) uses?  Can you console log the result of `$('body').find('#masonrygallery')` to see what it finds, if anything?  Maybe it's not finding the target element, or maybe there's more than one with the same `id`?

Comment: Perhaps you need to destroy previous mixitUp instance before intializing a new one. There is a destroy method in the api

Comment: @David Yes, the same log is shown for the first time I type as for the second time. Both times I see: `jQuery.fn.init [div#masonrygallery.masonrygallery, prevObject: jQuery.fn.init(1)]
0: div#masonrygallery.masonrygallery
length: 1`

Comment: @twan: Can you provide a [mcve] demonstrating the problem so we can observe it live?  If the AJAX call is working as expected then it can simply be mocked with a resolved promise that returns hard-coded test data.

Comment: You must delete the instance of MixItUp from the memory before your new ajax call, otherwise further instantiations on the same element will be blocked.  `try {
            $('#masongallary').mixItUp('destroy');
        }catch(x) {}


        $('#masongallary').mixItUp(...)`    .. in ajax.complete  put the above code to destroy mixItUp with try catch before initiating mixitup again..

Comment: In the documentation I see that there are some callback options for different lifecycle stages. You could try to add those with some logging to see if that better informs what the library is doing. I can't direct link but if you travel here and go to the "callbacks" section, you'll see what I'm referring to: https://www.kunkalabs.com/mixitup/docs/configuration-object/. In particular you may want to implement `onMixFail`.

Comment: @shotgun02 Thanks, I got it to work! You were right.